# Is it possible to reverse the dominance of the "eyes" versus "vision" tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Right now "vision" is synonyming into "eyes" which to me is backward...there are a lot of vision-based questions that aren't really about eyes per se, whereas the inverse is not true. I don't know if these are automatic categories based on frequency or something and I don't oppose them being synonyms, but I think "vision" should be the dominant category and tags for "eyes" should convert to vision, rather than the other way around, if this is possible.

Comment: absolutely agreed here

Comment: I also agree...

Comment: Yes, this should definitely be changed.

Comment: @AliceD Is this something you can do as a mod?

Comment: I de-synonymized them a while ago and forgot to post an answer to let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have de-synonymized the [vision](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/vision/info) and [eyes](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/eyes/info) tags. Honesty, I do not know why, how and when the synomyzation happened.

The vision tag is more appropriate for questions on visual ***function***, physiology and neuroscience.

> Questions regarding how the brain interprets information from the
>   eyes. Consider using the "eyes" tag for discussion of eye anatomy,
>   physiology and evolution.

The eyes tag is more appropriate for ***anatomy***, histology and underlying (physical) optics questions.

> The discussion of the anatomy and evolution of eyes. Consider using
>   the "vision" tag for questions regarding how the brain interprets
>   information from the eyes.